# Is there somewhere to be found a complete list of default accounts for PR15Q2.2 or an updated Generic Charts of Accounts file for version PR15Q2.2?

Tags: openbravo

I am working on creating a new charts of accounts file.
Started working with the coa file from here:
http://centralrepository.openbravo.com/openbravo/org.openbravo.forge.ui/ForgeModuleDetail/Generic-Chart-Of-Accounts
And using this as a guide:
http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Creating_Accounts_Files
When I look at the file and the guide there is a difference when it comes to the standard accounts.
These are not in the guide on the web but in the file:
"CB_EXPENSE_ACCT"
"CB_RECEIPT_ACCT"
"CH_EXPENSE_ACCT"
And these are not in the Generic Charts of Accounts file but in the guide on the web:
P_COGS_RETURN_ACCT
P_REVENUE_RETURN_ACCT
T_CREDIT_TRANS_ACCT
T_DUE_TRANS_ACCT
Is there somewhere to be found a complete list of default accounts for PR15Q2.2 or an updated Generic Charts of Accounts file for version PR15Q2.2?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use the testing spreadsheet from openbravo. The information in the wiki is indeed confusing, but in the spreadsheet you can paste your own COA and then debug until no errors are shown:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/openbravo/files/04-openbravo-accounting/Chart%20Of%20Accounts%20Test/

Hope it helps,

Regards

**EDIT:**

On the testing spreadsheet, the following default accounts are:

A_ACCUMDEPRECIATION_ACCT
A_DEPRECIATION_ACCT
B_ASSET_ACCT
B_EXPENSE_ACCT
B_INTRANSIT_ACCT
B_REVALUATIONGAIN_ACCT
B_REVALUATIONLOSS_ACCT
C_RECEIVABLE_ACCT
CB_ASSET_ACCT
CB_CASHTRANSFER_ACCT
CB_DIFFERENCES_ACCT
* CB_EXPENSE_ACCT
* CB_RECEIPT_ACCT
* CH_EXPENSE_ACCT
CURRENCYBALANCING_ACCT
DEFAULT_ACCT
INCOMESUMMARY_ACCT
NOTINVOICEDRECEIPTS_ACCT
P_ASSET_ACCT
P_COGS_ACCT
P_EXPENSE_ACCT
P_REVENUE_ACCT
SUSPENSEBALANCING_ACCT
SUSPENSEERROR_ACCT
T_CREDIT_ACCT
T_DUE_ACCT
V_LIABILITY_ACCT
W_DIFFERENCES_ACCT
WRITEOFF_ACCT

As per Openbravo pR15Q1.5 (released on the 19th of Juni 2015 - http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Release_Notes/3.0PR15Q1.5), a COA tested with this spreadsheet, can be imported into Openbravo Business Suite.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I totally agree with you. However, in this case I cannot provide any other additional information in the answer as the link is an Excel File which has to be downloaded.

Comment: @Hcorg -> You made me think and there you go :-)